# What Stack Exchange site should I use to ask programming questions based on the vision?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I don't know which Stack Exchange site I should use...

These are some examples of the question type I want to share:

- Is it possible to become a software developer in two years?
- Why don't the well-known applications in Windows use [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) or [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) technologies?
- Should I learn the [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) that I'll never use?

and the like.

Comment: Such questions, with little or no context whatsoever, are ideal for [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora). They are also the typical questions on [Stefan Mischook's livestreams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j831V8dzncE&lc=UgzlMVAsyk7Y868EeOB4AaABAg) (the first question is a super FAQ on the livestream (with many variations)).

Answer (score 5):

These questions are all either too broad or opinion-based to be acceptable anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about these questions you listed have problems:

> Is it possible to become a software developer in two years?

It is a kind of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question, but this is actually unanswerable, as it depends on the basis of programming skill, so it is opinion-based, and not suitable for the network.

> Why are the well-known applications in Windows don't use WPF or UWP technologies?

Which version of Windows are you implying to? Which apps? This question that could be part of [Super User](https://superuser.com/) need details or clarity or needs more focus.

> Should I learn the design patterns that I'll never use?

It is up to you, which the comments might imply, so it is also opinion-based.

---

Needless to say, there is no way these kinds of questions are answerable unless there is some context or anything that can make it answerable.

You can use [Jon Skeet's guide](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for writing good questions or follow the help pages to be able to get a good question with good answers.

Comment: "Why are the well-known applications in Windows don't use WPF or UWP technologies?" - **Is a horrible Super User question.**  The Super User community won't be able to answer such a broad question.  We don't know the reason why some applications have been updated to UWP applications and some applications have not been updated.  If a user were to ask that question on Super User I would vote to immediately close it as being "too broad" and/or seeking an opinion.  The question doesn't even specify which applications have not been upgraded. **One might be able to point to a future build.**

Comment: I specified that. Thanks for clarifications. Shall I give you a citation after the hard days of the work?